# Some GameObjects can't touch

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing game for iPhone and Android and i have different GameObjects and `GUITexture` and i have write code for touch event for all objects and everything was working perfectly. But after change my Main Camera angle some of the objects and `GUITexture`' which are in the corner of the screen that objects and `GUITexture's` touch method not calling. I found that if i am putting that object into middle to Screen then it's touch event working properly.

For touch i have used bellow code:

```
ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); //I can't get touch.position to work

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)){

       if(Physics.Raycast(ray,hit,1000)){

            if(hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Sound"){
```

can anybody help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more clear when talking about 'I can't get it to work'. What errors do you get? What have you tried? Also, next time, post your programming language as a tag.

To get the touch position and a ray to use with hittesting, try the following:

```
if(Input.touches.Count > 0)
{
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);
    // do stuff ...
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("No touches available");
}
```

`Input.touches` returns a list of objects representing the status of all touches during the last frame. Each entry represents a status of a finger touching the screen.

As for your hittest, you have 3 parameters in your `Physics.Raycast`.

1. The Ray, or the line on which you'd like to check.
2. Your output, `hit`.
3. The length of your ray, or your line.

I don't know for sure if your `hit` is being used correctly or not. To be sure, why don't you instantiate a variable before the hittest?

```
RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        // do stuff ...
```

And last but not least, the lenght or your ray. Is that necessary? In the example above, I left the variable out in its entirety. Good chance you moved your Camera so your object is now more than 1000 units away.